# Update Customer details automatically when custom module data updated

Tags: magento2, magento-1, event-observer, customer, customer-group

I have a custom table which holds membership numbers and there corresponding membership type. For example number: 10001, membership_type: Gold.

I have an observer which checks a customers input and assigns the customer to a group based on the membership number the have entered.

In the admin panel I have a member section which lists all membership number and their type in a grid.

What I would like to do is:

- When a membership number in the admin panel is deleted or membership type changed, i'd like to update the customer whose membership was amended and change their assigned customer group automatically.

Thanks

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

So I assume that you have a model set-up nicely for this memebership table.

Now what you can do is use the event.

```
$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after
$this->_eventPrefix.'_delete_after
```

Then on these events loop through the customers attached and make the appropriate updates.